# Laravel - связи данных

Tags: laravel

Начинаю изучать `laravel`, подскажите как правильно организовать связи. Структура следующая:

Есть таблица с городами:
`id = 1, city = Москва`

Есть таблица людей:
`id = 1, name = Вася, city_id = 1,2,3 (varchar)`

На выходе мне нужно вывести всех людей с присвоенными адресами:

Вася Москва, Казань, Пермь

Петя Казань, Саратов

и т.д.

Comment: Документацией у Laravel можно восхищаться, там все подробно написано, но Вы походу начали изучать этот фреймворк пропустив основы субд... Почитайте про организацию связей в субд и о первичных ключах и все поймете.

Comment: Меня больше всего пугает **city_id = 1,2,3** - если в одно поле попадает больше чем одна связь это уже не верно, посмотрите тему нормализации СУБД. Для этого используются таблицы связок, в вашем случае связь в laravel не будет работать, только ручные запросы потом еще и с разбором полей на php.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас связь [many-to-many](http://jtest.ru/bazyi-dannyix/sql-dlya-nachinayushhix-chast-3.html) (в одном городе много людей и  один человек в нескольких городах), то вам нужна промежуточная таблица с записями типа `city_id - user_id`
В laravel это организовано через функцию [`belongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) и pivot таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

Выше все верно написали. Но, если вы по каким-то причинам хотите хранить несколько городов именно в одном поле (плохая идея, но если вы совершенно точно уверенны, что понимаете что делаете и почему должно быть именно так), то используйте json. Последние версии myqsl поддерживают его, postgres поддерживает уже очень давно. Laravel начиная с версии 5.3 поддерживает работу с полями типа json. Посмотреть как с ним работать можно тут: https://mattstauffer.co/blog/new-json-column-where-and-update-syntax-in-laravel-5-3